# $\varphi$ continuous in every point $a\in A$ iff $\varphi_{|A}$ continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to understand these claims:

> Let $K\subset [0,1]$ the Cantor set. Define a function
>   $\varphi:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$, where $\varphi(x)=0$ for every $x\in K$
>   and $\varphi(x)=1$, if $x\notin K$. If $A=[0,1]\setminus K$, then $A$
>   is open and $\varphi_{|A}$ is constant (therefore continuous). Thus,
>   $\varphi:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ is continuous at every point $a\in A$.

I didn't understand why $\varphi_{|A}$ continuous $\implies$ $\varphi$ continuous in every point $a\in A$.

I know we always have: $\varphi$ continuous in every point $a\in A$ $\implies$ $\varphi_{|A}$ continuous.

Why the converse is true in this case?

Maybe we have to use this theorem, but I don't know how:

> If $X=\cup_{\lambda\in L} A_{\lambda}$ and $f_{|A_{\lambda}}$ are
>   continuous and $A_{\lambda}$ are open sets for every $\lambda\in L$,
>   then $f:X\to \mathbb R$ is continuous.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The point is this:

Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $U \subset X$ be open. If a function $f: X\to Y$ is such that $f|_U$ is continuous, then for each point $x \in U$, the map $f$ is continuous at $x$.

**Proof:** Fix $x \in U$, and let $V\subset Y$ be any open neighborhood of $f(x)$.

Since $f|_U$ is continuous, there exists an open set $W \subset U$ such that $x \in W$ and $f(W) \subset V$. Since $W$ is open in $U$ and $U$ is open in $X$, it follows that $W$ is open in $X$.

Therefore, for any open neighborhood $V \ni f(x)$, there exists an open set $W\subset X$ such that $x\in W$ and $f(W) \subset V$, which shows that $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Comment: Sure no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Use the fact that $A$ is open (without it the result is not necessarily true). Intuitively, continuity at a point $a$ is a condition that only depends on a neighborhood of $a$.